# Delete mysql record older than 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

How to delete mysql record older than 30 days? my code will delete all the records even which are inserted yesterday.

```
require('../conn_db.php');
mysql_select_db("my_news",$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_news WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");
mysql_close("my_news");
```

And mysql table

```
date int(10)
1321095600
1322107200
...
1328288400
1328290440
```

Comment: What you show looks okay, but should not work at all: It should throw a syntax error because `date` is a reserved word. Are you sure you are looking at the right query

Comment: Using `SET NAMES` is exactly why `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not safe. Use [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) instead.

Comment: Is there a reason why use int instead of date datatype to store dates?

Comment: You're talking about "30 days" and "months", which are in about 50% of the cases not the same. And do  you really want to delete the data? Don't you rather do this WHERE clause on the SELECT that reads your news items?

Comment: just one observation; there are two different approaches either using the server time as provided by PHP or the server time provided by mysql. those may differ from each other, even if both are in the same machine.

Comment: Is your date field int or datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MySQL Table does not store a date, but rather a unix timestamp (judging from the data you have provided). To delete do the following:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_news WHERE date < ".strtotime('-1 month'));
```

Answer (score 11):

First off, if you really want to delete records older than 30 days, use `INTERVAL 30 DAY` instead, when you use `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` you will delete records added on Mars 31st, when it's April 1st.

Also, your date-column is of type `int`, and DATE_SUB() will return a date in this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, so they are not comparable. You could do this to work around that problem:

```
DELETE FROM my_news WHERE date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Comment: I would like to upvote this just because it's the first answer to actually explain why the OP's method doesn't work, but taking a timestamp, substracting 30 days, formatting it and then turning it back to timestamp is just way too clunky.

Comment: I agree, it's heavy and it's ugly, but it solves the problem without having OP change his table-structure and it does not deviate that much from his initial query.

Answer (score 3):

Try this .

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_news WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL is fine but you have confused your datatypes. Just make a call to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

```
require('../conn_db.php');
mysql_select_db("my_news",$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_news WHERE date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))");
mysql_close("my_news");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the prettiest, but since you seems to store your time as an int. How about just subtracting 30 days from now, and compare to that value:

```
DELETE 
FROM my_news 
WHERE `date` < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 30))
```

Answer (score 1):

do it like

```
 $time_ago = strtotime("-30 day");
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_news WHERE date < $time_ago");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$expiretime = time() - 2592000; //1 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_news WHERE date < ".$expiretime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query:

```
DELETE FROM my_news WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW() ,date )>30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 MONTH')` instead of INTERVAL 1 MONTH in the second parameter of `DATE_SUB()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_news WHERE date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");
```